# counsel-git-grep: why does it ignore .gitignore paths?

Tags: search, git, counsel

Currently there is an issue (or else I can't figure it out) with counsel-git-grep-function: why does this function not ignore the files in .gitignore when searching? It would be a useful function if it would ignore the paths set in .gitignore. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your `counsel-git-grep-cmd(-default)` variable(s)?

Comment: Thanks! This is what I get: counsel-git-grep-cmd-default is a variable defined in ‘counsel.el’.
Its value is "git --no-pager grep -n --no-color -I -e \"%s\""

Comment: I guess counsel uses that command. You could try the command on the terminal to check if something is wrong there...